# CodeIgniter + Doctrine: CRUD in Controller?

Tags: codeigniter, doctrine, controller, crud

I am a newbie to MVC, CodeIgniter and Doctrine, so maybe my question is not that relevant. Pardon me if thats the case.

I've been reading the CodeIgniter + Doctrine tutorials on [PHPandStuff.com](http://www.phpandstuff.com/articles/codeigniter-doctrine-from-scratch-day-1-install-and-setup). I really like whatever I have seen of Doctrine and wish to use it for my project. However, since all database related operations should be kept in the Model and not the Controller, shouldnt the CRUD operations which use Doctrine also be loacted in the Doctrine Model instead? If so, then how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to write the DQL into the Controller (which is a good thing) you can put separate functions into your model that just work with the functionality provided by the extended classes.

For example, if you have a class called `User`, and you need to save it, you simple could do

```
class User extends BaseUser //or whatever you want
{
    public function saveNewUser($data) {
        //setting the userdata e.g. $this->username
        try {
            $this->save();
            ....
        } catch (Doctrine_Connection_Mysql_Exception $e) {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

So you have all functions inside the model just as you wanted it.